QGIS/GDAL warp(reproject) throws 'ERROR 5: dfMax should be strictly greater than dfMin' when run in Python script
I have ~ 150 .xyz-files (DEMs) which I try to reproject. When I reproject them within QGIS via raster -- > warp everything works fine.  First I tried the batch processing option with warp(reproject), but it got stuck each time at a random data file (this seems to be a known bug in QGIS > 3.26).
Howver, when I try to reproject them within a Python script I get the error ERROR 5: dfMax should be strictly greater than dfMin.
What is the problem and what can I do about it?
This is my code in Python:
def reprojectFiles(inputfolderpath, outputfolderpath, crs, fileformat):
    for file_name in os.listdir(inputfolderpath):
        if fileformat in file_name:
            INPUT = inputfolderpath + '/' + file_name
            OUTPUT = outputfolderpath + '/' + file_name
            print(INPUT)
            print(OUTPUT)
            processing.run("gdal:warpreproject",
                           {'INPUT':INPUT,
                            'TARGET_CRS':crs,
                            'OUTPUT':OUTPUT
                           }
            )


pathInputfolder = r'Path\to\Inputfolder'
pathOutputfolder = r'Path\to\Outputfolder'
crs = 'epsg:25832'
fileformat = '.xyz'




Not an answer to the question, but I managed to reprject my data by using the batch process in QGIS 3.10, so in a version in which the bug (getting stuck in the batch processing) doesn't exist.

By the error the script seems to believe that in some file the maxx or maxy  coordinate of the data is not bigger than minx/miny. Are all the .xyz files valid? Have you tested in a directory that has only one or two certainly valid .xyz files?

Unfortunately I'm not able to share the data, as they were sent by a customer and I think the data are not open. However, I did reproject the file, which led to that error, within QGIS by applying the warp(reproject)-tool on it and I didn't get an error and the data looked good.
Also, the batch processing (QGIS 3.10) didn't throw any errors and the resulting file looks good!
